# Convert a rows list to pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe (df) with very many rows and two columns (col1, col2), though I want to get a dataframe with only the top 30 rows. I've seen that I can display them with:

df.show(30)

But this isn't what I want to do, I need an actual dataframe with only these 30 rows. I've also seen that I can run:

df.head(30) or df.take(30)

But these don't output a dataframe but rather a list of the form [Row(col1=100, col2=200), Row(col1=300, col2=500), ...]

What I am wanting to know is how I can convert this list [Row(col1=100, col2=200), Row(col1=300, col2=500), ...] back into a dataframe. I have tried DataFrame and createDataFrame, but these are throwing up errors. Specifically, I have tried:

```
df_list=df.head(30)
df_Columns = ["col1","col2"]
new_df=DataFrame(df_list, df_Columns)
```

But this is throwing up errors. I am at a loss as to how to do this seemingly simple task, so I am looking for a straightforward method to do so (convert the df.head(30) list back to a pyspark dataframe). Any guidance or insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you need the dataframe to return, you can use `df.limit(30)`.

Comment: Amazing! That was the method I was looking for. Thanks so much kindly Emma!